# unable to commit & push reverted commit to bitbucket from InteliJ UI

Tags: intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am new to *InteliJ* + *Bitbucket* integration.

after clicking *revert commit* on specific commit I pushed before -

1. local file is changed to the way it looked before the commit
   **but**
2. no files appears on the *local changes* window
3. while running git status command on the terminal getting:
   *You are currently reverting commit a3b1cd9.
   (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
   (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
   (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)*

any idea if there is any way to progress with this situation via the Intelij UI to commit and push this reverting to bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to click on push icon on top, and then popup with option to push the reverting commit is presented.
unlike regular commit that right after changing files all of them are ready to commit on  *local changes* window, and push popup appears only after marking them and clicking commit button...